# NPM packages are not running with the node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, npm, hyper

[image]

`Mysupername` is the value that got printed out and not the expected output.

[image]

I already tried reinstalling it. I used `npm install prompt -sync` to use it with JavaScript inside Visual Studio Code but I don't know where I am going wrong. I have already added the variables in system advanced setting.

Visual Studio Code error message if I try to use `prompt` or `alert` inside and run through code runner extension:

[image]

Comment: please post code not images of code ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a slight mistake with your code. Firstly, the reason why it is printing `Mysupername` to the console is because you provided `console.log` with a string. Instead just provide the variable name like this:

```
const superheroes = require('superheroes');

var Mysupername = superheroes.random();

console.log(Mysupername);
```

Now, the reason why `prompt` isn't working is because you never imported the library into your code, you can do it by the following:

```
const prompt = require("prompt");
```

Final note, `alert` is only available when running javascript through a browser.

Comment: That does solve the problem. Thank you very much for your help and time. I am new and still learning but I'll work harder next time.